# Force close a stream

Tags: c#, io, filestream

I have an issue from time to time, I have a few `StreamReader`s and `StreamWriter`s in my program that read info and write it. They go right about 99% of the time, but once in a while I end up with a `StreamWriter` that won't close, on a piece of code I've run multiple times.

This tends to happen if I spam a function, but I am trying to find a safe way to guarantee a steam disposed. Anyone know how?

Comment: "Won't close" is vague. What do you mean by this? What indications lead you to believe they won't close? What's does it mean - "spam a function"? Invoke the function numerous times in a short time period?

Comment: What is the scope in which you're using the streamreader/writer? Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes, I was very vague. I must appologise. I start a stream using streamreader to read a file, then dispose of it using XX.dispose();. Every once in a while though it won't dispose, and I'll end up with "file is in use" until I restart my program. This is the error I am trying to figure out if there is a fix, as I'm already using the fixes proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try a `using` statement [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Initialization)){

   //your code

}
```

this can be useful:

[Closing Stream Read and Stream Writer when the form exits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3897996/735864)

Also you could use a `Try` Block

```
try
{
    //Declare your streamwriter
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Initialization);
}
catch
{
    //Handle the errors
}
finally
{
    sw.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Yes. I'll second this. There are likely more IDisposables in the mix. Use the using pattern for these too.

Answer (score 1):

If the stream's scope is local, always use the following construct:

```
using (var stream = new Stream())
{
    ...do stream work here...
}
```

If on the other hand you are using the stream as a class field then implement the `IDisposable` pattern and dispose your stream objects when disposing your class: [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the StreamWriter in a using statement is how I usually ensure it is disposed of.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\AFile.txt"))
{
    //do some stuff with writer
}
```

An alternative would be to use a `finally` block.